# Why password becomes incorrect after generating keytab in Kerberos?

Tags: kerberos

In my Kerberos system:

1. run `kinit test` and input `passwd`, succeed.
2. generate keytab by `kadmin.local -q "xst -k test.keytab test"`.
3. run `kinit test` and input `passwd`, failed:

   ```
   kinit: Password incorrect while getting initial credentials
   ```
4. run `kinit -k -t test.keytab test`, succeed.

Is this normal ? If not, what are possible reasons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I found that the attribute `krbLastPwdChange(a timestamp value)` in kerberos's database changed after I run:

```
kadmin.local -q "xst -k test.keytab test"
```

While add the option `-norandkey` will just create the keytab without changing password:

```
kadmin.local -q "xst -norandkey -k test.keytab test"
```

I can not find the detail document about `kadmin xst`.

Comment: So as implied by this answer: It seems that the procedure to allow login via password AND keytab is: 1. Set the password 2. Create keytab with `-norandkey` -- That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 7):

This is by design.  You cannot have both a password and a keytab in Kerberos.  The reason is if both were enabled, if someone was able to pull a keytab on your behalf or was in possession of a copy of your keytab, then they could masquerade as you and you would never know it.  They would be able to generate a TGT via kinit.

By pulling a keytab, the password is invalidated, so if you then tried to log in with a password, you would get an error.  And even if you didn't know exactly what was going on, if you reset your password, it would invalidate the keytab.

Answer (score 1):

For one simple reason:

`kinit` tells you that the client has not been found in the database, right? By default, when `kinit` is invoked with a keytab it uses the default server pricipal to obtain TGT. In your case `host/<hostname>@REALM` but your keytab contains a key for principal `test@REALM`.

I had this issue too until I have asked the MIT Kereros mailing list.

Comment: I am very sorry that I missed the principal in the command of step 4. I've fixed it. Invoking kinit with keytab is succeed, my problem is why using password failed. Thanks.

Comment: Are you certail and the password has not been changed? Please create a new keytab with you given password using `ktutil` and compare the results. You also should try with `KRB5_TRACE`.